# Profiling WPF application

Tags: wpf, profiling

I have a WPF application, that is sometimes freezing for maybe a half minute and then works fine.
I am thinking to profile that application.
Anybody knows a good tutorial of how to profile WPF application?
Or anybody has any idea on finding a way to know when it is freezing?
The freezing is not consistent, and not related to any usage pattern

Thanks for help.

Ghassan

Answer (score 10):

There is a toolset in the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx) called WPFPerf - it has a set of tools (like Perforator) that help specifically with WPF debugging and profiling.  [Here's a quick guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) on these tools.

For general .net profiling, [RedGate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) or [JetBrains' dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) are great.  There is also some [profiling included in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) 2005/2008 (and better ones in 2010?).

Comment: According to this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), VS2010 Performance Profiler is not available in all editions.

Comment: @PhilipRieck: What is the current alternative for WPF Performance Suite for profiling .NET 4.5 apps? I would very appreciate you if you take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33468572/3345644).

Answer (score 2):

Profiling is overkill. During that half minute, it's waiting for something. [Just pause it and see what it's waiting for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

Comment: While I agree that this is a good technique to use in general, I disagree that it is always caused by an infinite loop.  There could be blocking going on by some API waiting for a resource.  There's a lot of reasons your UI could freeze that are not related to an infinite loop.  I only say this just to make sure no one goes on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @Anderson: OK, I re-worded it to take out the "nearly infinite loop" part. The principle is the same. During that half minute, it's in a state in which it is waiting for something, after which it will resume useful work. Just pause it, and you'll see what it's waiting for, whether it's a low-level loop, getting a resource, whatever. People think this is hard, and it's not.